# Cannot load files from CloudFront? Getting ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Response Headers

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=2628000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 96873
content-type: application/javascript
date: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 14:30:08 GMT
etag: "49edcc------------------cbed1"
last-modified: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 11:53:50 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
via: 1.1 bdd06c9cf78f-------d79762.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

Request Headers

```
:authority: d2kr3rn0m64oxi.cloudfront.net
:method: GET
:path: /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

What I did from the S3 console

From S3, I've changed the metadata for `wp-content` and `wp-includes` folder to `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: *"From S3, I've changed the metadata for wp-content and wp-includes folder to Content-Encoding: gzip."*  Why did you do this?

Comment: adding metadata as gzip doesn't compress objects on S3 automatically and browser sees the content-encoding header and throw error , use cloudfront compression if you haven't compressed before uploading it to s3.